# Javascript Continue Running Code After Error

Tags: javascript, sql-server, deployment

I am doing testing on some values to see which gives the correct output.

I require a redeployment to the server every time I made changes to the code, which affects the concurrent users on the server.

I would like to minimize that.

Is it possible to continue running the code even though errors are caught?

*Javascript:*

```
var schedule = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").value;
console.log("schedule is " + schedule);  //returns UNDEFINED

var schedule2 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").length;
console.log("schedule2 is " + schedule2); //returns UNDEFINED

var schedule3 = document.getElementById('ddlExecutionSchedule'); 
console.log("schedule3 is " + schedule3); //returns HTML OBJECT

var schedule4 = document.getElementById('ddlExecutionSchedule').value;
console.log("schedule4 is " + schedule4); //returns UNDEFINED

var schedule5 = document.getElementById('ddlExecutionSchedule').length;
console.log("schedule5 is " + schedule5); //returns UNDEFINED

var schedule6 = document.getElementById(<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>);
console.log("schedule6 is " + schedule6); //returns NULL

var options = schedule.getElementsByTagName('input');
//^ = The line above caught an error of <Uncaught TypeError: 
      Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

var options2 = schedule2.getElementsByTagName('input');
//^ = To test

...
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` and `catch` would help:

```js
var schedule1 = document.getElementById("id1").length;
console.log("schedule1 is " + schedule1); //returns UNDEFINED

var schedule2 = document.getElementById("id1");
console.log("schedule2 is " + schedule2);

try {
  var options1 = schedule1.getElementsByTagName('input');
  console.log('options1: ' + options1);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('error: '+ err.message);
}
var options2 = schedule2.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log('options2: ' + options2);
```

```html
<label id="id1"><input></label>
```